# Modifying VBA code to change value in string to communicate with NVA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to modify some VBA code that was passed onto me from the previous grad-student of my lab. 
I am trying to make it so the program starts at the fundamental frequency, takes data, adds 10 hz and takes data again. I want it to do this a specified number of times. eg. F10 " 100"
The problem is I am communicating with a Rhonda and schwarz network vector analyzer and the frequency is written in the string. 
Here is the original code :

```
Private WithEvents ZVX_IF As VIF
'Public command_s As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Buffer As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Trace, Stim As Variant
Dim dt As String, wbNam As String

Set ZVX_IF = New VIF

Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = "---"

'clear previous data
Range("A4:C4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

command_s = Space(20)


With ZVX_IF
    If .OpenDevice(Tabelle3.Range("B1").Value) = True Then
        .ReadString "*IDN?", Buffer: Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = Buffer 
'read out instrument type
        .WriteString ":FORMat:DATA REAL" 'set transfer to real format (speed)
        .ReadString ":INSTrument:PORT:COUNt?", Buffer: 
Tabelle3.Range("C2").Value = Buffer ' detect no of ports
        If Buffer = "2" Then

            .WriteString command_y     'set measured quantity to Sxx
            .WriteString ":CALCulate1:FORMat REAL"        'set format to real
            .WriteString ":INITiate1:CONTinuous OFF"      'set single sweep

    'ENTER YOUR HARMONIC
    'Center the analyzer on a harmonic
    .WriteString "FREQ:CENT 446.26477 MHz"
    'Set Span to
    .WriteString "FREQ:SPAN 912 kHz"
    'now memorize current timer value
    t = Timer()
    'display current time
    Tabelle3.Range("I16").Value = Now
    '___________________________________
    'start one sweep and wait for completion
    .WriteString ":INITiate1:IMMediate;*WAI"                    'launch single sweep and wait to finish
    'get stimulus data
    .ReadFloatArray "TRAC:STIM? CH1DATA", Stim                  ' get stimulus data
    'write stimulus values to sheet
    For Index = LBound(Stim) To UBound(Stim)
        Tabelle3.Range("A4").Offset(Index, 0).Value = Stim(Index) / 1000000000#
    Next Index

    Else
            Get_Spara16.Show '4-port instrument
    End If
Else
    Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = "INSTRUMENT NOT FOUND"
    'Save the workbook
    'wbNam = "DD_Test0pcnt_"
    'dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=wbNam & dt
    'Sheet1.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\schwarz\Documents\SuckIt" & dt & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

    End If
End With

KeepRunning

End Sub
```

1.)I need a way to have "446.26477 MHz"  be set at what ever frequency I want
2.)for it to loop, at each new loop to add "10 Mhz" to "446.26477 Mhz", or any specified step amount
3.) to loop a specified number of time , eg 100 steps/loops , then end.

The following was with the help of Tim Williams, the addition line is working, but the value of freq is being reset to the initial value at the top of each loop.

```
Private WithEvents ZVX_IF As VIF            'Public command_s As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const NUM_REPS As Long = 2          'works as expexted
Dim freq As Variant, i As Long           'the i works as expexted
Dim Buffer As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Trace, Stim As Variant
Dim dt As String





Set ZVX_IF = New VIF

Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = "---"

'clear previous data
Range("A4:C4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

command_s = Space(20)


With ZVX_IF
If .OpenDevice(Tabelle3.Range("B1").Value) = True Then
    .ReadString "*IDN?", Buffer: Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = Buffer 'read 
out instrument type
    .WriteString ":FORMat:DATA REAL"                            'set 
transfer to real format (speed)
    .ReadString ":INSTrument:PORT:COUNt?", Buffer: 
Tabelle3.Range("C2").Value = Buffer ' detect no of ports
    If Buffer = "2" Then

    .WriteString command_y                              'set measured 
quantity to Sxx
    .WriteString ":CALCulate1:FORMat REAL"              'set format to real
    .WriteString ":INITiate1:CONTinuous OFF"            'set single sweep

    For i = 1 To NUM_REPS           'works as expexted

    freq = 15.005005            'works as expexted

    Cells(11, 11) = freq            'not displaying steps



    'ENTER YOUR HARMONIC
    'Center the analyzer on a harmonic
    .WriteString "FREQ:CENT " & freq & " MHz"
    'Set Span to
    .WriteString "FREQ:SPAN 912 kHz"
    'now memorize current timer value
    t = Timer()
    'display current time
    Tabelle3.Range("I16").Value = Now
    '___________________________________
    'start one sweep and wait for completion
    .WriteString ":INITiate1:IMMediate;*WAI"                    'launch 
single sweep and wait to finish
    'get stimulus data
    .ReadFloatArray "TRAC:STIM? CH1DATA", Stim                  ' get 
stimulus data
    'write stimulus values to sheet
    For Index = LBound(Stim) To UBound(Stim)
        Tabelle3.Range("A4").Offset(Index, 0).Value = Stim(Index) / 
1000000000#
    Next Index

    '______________________________________
    'now get trace data
    .ReadFloatArray ":TRACe? CH1Data", Trace                    'get all of 
channel 1 data
    'show elapsed timer value on sheet
    Tabelle3.Range("I44").Value = (Timer() - t) * 1000
    'write data to worksheet
    For Index = LBound(Trace) To UBound(Trace) Step 2
        Tabelle3.Range("B4").Offset(Index / 2, 0).Value = Trace(Index)
        Tabelle3.Range("C4").Offset(Index / 2, 0).Value = Trace(Index + 1)
    Next Index

    Cells(11, 12) = freq
    freq = freq + 10  '!!!!!!!not working!!!!!
    Cells(11, 13) = freq


    'Save the workbook and Enter the Name you want it saved as
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Profesor 
Xavier\Desktop\ZHU\Data run\_Test_loop_" & dt & ".xls", FileFormat:=56

    Next i          'works as expexted


    Else
            Get_Spara16.Show '4-port instrument
    End If
Else
    Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = "INSTRUMENT NOT FOUND"
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("0:N10")` - this is not a valid range.  `For Each samplefrequency` missing `... In (somethinghere)`

Comment: Pretty difficult to make suggestions without being able to debug your code.  Withing the loop you're writing the results to the same location each time. Is that intentional?

Comment: I have located the issue. I used a print to cell function to have it print the value of freq at the top of the loop , before the add, and after the add. my output for both iterations of the loop where 15,15,25 retrospectively. suggesting that the value is being reset at the top of the loop back to the original value for some resone. I do not yet know why.  I have now updated the code to be self-contained and localized to eliminate problems. It writes to a new file each iteration. the code in the original post , second entry, has ben changed to reflect the current code to date

Comment: I moved the frequency outside the loop. DUUU, that worked.. It seems to run properly now. I will try once more. I f it continues to work I will post code as answer.  Is there a way I can credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outline of what you need:

```
Const NUM_REPS As Long = 10
Dim freq as Double, i As Long

freq = 446.26477

For i = 1 to NUM_REPS 

    '.....
    .WriteString "FREQ:CENT " & freq & " MHz"
    '.....

    freq = freq + 10

Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. It was helpful. however the program is no longer loging my real and imaginary values. Nor is it saving the data to a file any more. Thoughts? see original post for up to date code

Comment: it turns out that uncomenting "keep ruining" allowed the program to take data and save. But then It failed to loop, so I had to edit the module keep running. Now it records data, loops the specified number of times , and saves data . But is no longer steeping up by increments.   I have traced both the table file and the module file and see no reason why it should not be steeping up. Im at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

the correctly working code

```
Private WithEvents ZVX_IF As VIF            'Public command_s As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const NUM_REPS As Long = 2          'works as expexted
Dim freq As Variant, i As Long           'the i works as expexted
Dim Buffer As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Trace, Stim As Variant
Dim dt As String





Set ZVX_IF = New VIF

Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = "---"

'clear previous data
Range("A4:C4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

command_s = Space(20)
freq = 15.005005            'set as primary frequency


With ZVX_IF
If .OpenDevice(Tabelle3.Range("B1").Value) = True Then
    .ReadString "*IDN?", Buffer: Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = Buffer 'read out 
instrument type
    .WriteString ":FORMat:DATA REAL"                            'set transfer to real 
format (speed)
    .ReadString ":INSTrument:PORT:COUNt?", Buffer: Tabelle3.Range("C2").Value = 
Buffer ' detect no of ports
    If Buffer = "2" Then

    .WriteString command_y                              'set measured quantity to Sxx
    .WriteString ":CALCulate1:FORMat REAL"              'set format to real
    .WriteString ":INITiate1:CONTinuous OFF"            'set single sweep

    For i = 1 To NUM_REPS           'works as expexted







    'ENTER YOUR HARMONIC
    'Center the analyzer on a harmonic
    .WriteString "FREQ:CENT " & freq & " MHz"
    'Set Span to
    .WriteString "FREQ:SPAN 912 kHz"
    'now memorize current timer value
    t = Timer()
    'display current time
    Tabelle3.Range("I16").Value = Now
    '___________________________________
    'start one sweep and wait for completion
    .WriteString ":INITiate1:IMMediate;*WAI"                    'launch single sweep 
and wait to finish
    'get stimulus data
    .ReadFloatArray "TRAC:STIM? CH1DATA", Stim                  ' get stimulus data
    'write stimulus values to sheet
    For Index = LBound(Stim) To UBound(Stim)
        Tabelle3.Range("A4").Offset(Index, 0).Value = Stim(Index) / 1000000000#
    Next Index

    '______________________________________
    'now get trace data
    .ReadFloatArray ":TRACe? CH1Data", Trace                    'get all of channel 1 
data
    'show elapsed timer value on sheet
    Tabelle3.Range("I44").Value = (Timer() - t) * 1000
    'write data to worksheet
    For Index = LBound(Trace) To UBound(Trace) Step 2
        Tabelle3.Range("B4").Offset(Index / 2, 0).Value = Trace(Index)
        Tabelle3.Range("C4").Offset(Index / 2, 0).Value = Trace(Index + 1)
    Next Index


    freq = freq + 10  



    'Save the workbook and Enter the Name you want it saved as
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Profesor Xavier\Desktop\ZHU\Data 
 run\_Test_loop_" & dt & ".xls", FileFormat:=56

    Next i          'works as expexted


    Else
            Get_Spara16.Show '4-port instrument
    End If
Else
    Tabelle3.Range("B2").Value = "INSTRUMENT NOT FOUND"
End If
End With

End Sub
```